# Extract specific data from multidimensional array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, extract

I have a small problem. I'm trying to extract data from `[user]` but I can seem to get it right. Can someone please give me one example of how to extract for example the users id and from there I'm golden. This is the `$_SESSION` array (what the session contains), if that's any help.

```
 Array ( [__default] => Array ( 
                            [session.counter] => 3
                            [session.timer.start] => 1307209662 
                            [session.timer.last] => 1307209693 
                            [session.timer.now] => 1307209701 
                            [session.client.browser] => Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:2.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/4.0.1 
                            [registry] => JRegistry Object ( 
                                                            [_defaultNameSpace] => session
                                                            [_registry] => Array ( 
                                                                                    [session] => Array ( 
                                                                                                        [data] => stdClass Object ( ) 
                                                                                                        ) 
                                                                                ) 
                                                            [_errors] => Array ( ) 
                                                            ) 
                            [user] => JUser Object ( 
                                                    [id] => 0 
                                                    [name] => 
                                                    [username] => 
                                                    [email] => 
                                                    [password] => 
                                                    [password_clear] => 
                                                    [usertype] => 
                                                    [block] => 
                                                    [sendEmail] => 0 
                                                    [gid] => 0 
                                                    [registerDate] => 
                                                    [lastvisitDate] => 
                                                    [activation] => 
                                                    [params] => 
                                                    [aid] => 0 
                                                    [guest] => 1 
                                                    [_params] => JParameter Object ( [_raw] => 
                                                                                    [_xml] => 
                                                                                    [_elements] => Array ( ) [_elementPath] => Array (                                                                                                                                                              [0] => C:\xampp\htdocs\libraries\joomla\html\parameter\element )
                                                                                                                                                            [_defaultNameSpace] => _default 
                                                                                                                                                            [_registry] => Array ( 
                                                                                                                                                                                    [_default] => Array ( 
                                                                                                                                                                                                        [data] => stdClass Object ( ) 
                                                                                                                                                                                                        ) 
                                                                                                                                                                                ) 
                                                                                                                                                            [_errors] => Array ( ) 
                                                                                    ) 
                                                    [_errorMsg] => [_errors] => Array ( ) 
                                                    ) 
                            [session.token] => 971893bd69fff85ea2a006788a28b15d 
                        ) 
    [referrerid] => AUPRS-JOHNDOE
    )
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow - one of the best ways to help people answer your question is to nicely format any code in your question. Check out the helpful notes here: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: If this is a Joomla session, then there are probably wrapper functions which can accomplish getting some user information. Also, *how exactly* did you try to access the data?

Comment: i'm trying to include some scripts into my joomla based site, one example would be ajaxim from ajaxim.com and i need to check outside joomla if the user is logged in, to extract his username,id,password and other related info about him to use in ajaxim or future scripts that i want to integrate.

Answer (score 1):

```
$user = $_SESSION['user'];
echo $user->id;
```

This seems to be what you need.

Answer (score 0):

This would output the user name: (if there was any)

```
 print $_SESSION["__default"]["user"]->name;
```

You first need to overcome the `__default` key index within the $_SESSION array. Likewise is `user` an array key. But what the `user` entry contains is an object, so you need the `->` object arrow thingy to finally access the `name`.

Also I would not rely on `__default` being a given. Don't know anything about Joomla, but the $_SESSION array structure might be more flexible. Hencewhy it's advisable to find a function which instead fetches the user object for you.

Comment: Mario, i eventualy found a solution, but it wasn't as elegant and clean as yours so i ditched it for yours. Your solution is perfect. For refference, my not so clean solution was this function getvalue($value,$key,$what)
{
 $info[$key]=$value;
 echo $info[$what];
}
$array=$_SESSION['__default']['user'];
array_walk($array,"getvalue","username");